# React MSAL authentication failing after deployment of static web app

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, azure-static-web-app

I have a static web app with some config settings.

[image]

I created a React app with MSAL authentication.

On clicking this URL:

[image]

I see this on F12 -> Network:

[image]

(tenant id missing in request URL). I have that in config setting. Why is it not able to read the value from config setting? What am I missing?

Sharing my code:

authConfig.ts

```
import { Configuration } from "@azure/msal-browser";

// Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID}`,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID}`,
        redirectUri: "/",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "/"
    }
};

// scopes
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: [`api://${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID}/user_impersonation`]
  };

// endpoints 
export const config = {
    endpoint: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI}/api/v1/jobs`
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "2.34.0",
    "@azure/msal-common": "11.0.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "1.5.4",
    "@fluentui/react": "8.106.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "@types/node": "16.18.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "i18next": "22.4.9",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "12.1.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/node": "7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "7.16.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.12.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "5.14.5"
  }
}
```

When I run locally, it reads the values from .env file:

```
REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID= some value
REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID= some value
REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID= some value
REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI= some value
```

Before deployment I update .env to:

```
REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID= 
REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID= 
REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID= 
REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI=
```

My understanding is that after I deploy, it reads the values from static web app config instead of .env.

Comment: We need more information on how you're getting that tenand id from the config file.

Comment: Updated the question with the code. Thank you!

Comment: In the question you have mentioned that it is failing after deployment. In the context of your code, there's probably something wrong with the environment variables. Either you haven't set them in the "deployment" environment or there something wrong with the environment variables.